# Laravel admin dashboard authentication system

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to guard admin dashboard with middleware. Admin can access the dashboard if admin loged in with proper credentials. But it not working. Please help me. Please help me. After successful login, dashboard not opening.
after successful login page redirecting back to login page. I have change the redirection to another page which is not guard with middleware. Then it's working properly. with proper credentials it's redirecting to that page. but if dashboard not opening.
What to do?

> **I have already added middleware in kernel.php.**

route/web.php-

```
Route::group(['middleware'=> ['admin']], function(){

            
            Route::get('dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('admin.dashboard');
});
```

Middleware-

```
class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Check if the user is authenticated as an admin
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        // If not authenticated as an admin, redirect to login page
        return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    }
}
```

Auth.php-

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

Model -

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    protected $guard = 'admin';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password',

    ];

}
```

Controller-

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard')->with('ssc', 'done.');
        }

        return redirect()->route('admin.login')->with('error', 'Invalid credentials.');
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        return redirect('/admin/login');
    }
```

Please help me. After successful login, dashboard not opening.

Comment: Not sure if related to your problem, but I'd recommend you don't use 2 separate Classes for Users and Admins. **Users are Users**; an Admin is a Role that can be applied to your Users. I've been working with Laravel for a long time, and personally, I've never been able to successfully get multiple User models working; Laravel is just not built to support that by default.

Comment: @TimLewis is right you can add one field in the database users table with user_type where you can achieve this and create a middleware which is responsible for the if user type is admin or user then redirect to the next otherwise redirect to the login route.

Comment: Yup! A simple `user_type`, or a more robust `Role` model/table/relationship, or using any of the available Permissions packages should accomplish this in a way that works with Laravel.

Comment: Another package is `spatie/laravel-permission` which is famous for roles and permission You can use this package.